# Python – Nested FOR Loop Over 2D NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, neural-network

I'm learning neural networks by building my own framework and I've encountered a problem when trying to code *Step Activation Function*. This is what has gotten me closest to my goal so far:

```
import numpy as np

def step_function(layer_output):
    for row in layer_output:
        return np.array([0 if element <= 0 else 1 for element in row])
```

I'm trying to loop through each element in each row and check if the IF statement is correct or not for that element. Here's what happens on some example numbers (as a NumPy array, because that's what is my layer output format):

```
numbers = np.array([[1, -2, -3],
                    [0, 4, 5]])

activation = step_function(numbers)
print(activation)

>>>
[1 0 0]
```

The loop gets stuck on the first row. This is what i want as an output:

```
>>>
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

I would be thankful for any ideas on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the 'return' key word takes the argument passed to it, stops the function currently running and returns the argument where the function was called. That's the reason your function 'stops prematurely'.
Instead, what you can do is:

```
import numpy as np

def step_function(layer_output):
    output = np.zeros_like(layer_output)
    for i, row in enumerate(layer_output):
        output[i] = np.array([0 if element <= 0 else 1 for element in row])
    return output
```

But it would be far simpler and faster to just do a threshold operation directly on the whole array

```
import numpy as np

def step_function(layer_output):
    return (layer_output>0).astype(int)
```